# Converting data in XML to something like arraylist, cursor

Tags: java, android, xml

I have XML code (data form database) and I would like to move this data from XML to something like cursor or arraylist.
It is possible? How to do that?

Comment: There's a lot of XML parsing API's available and I think the JDK itself has one built-in. Just Google it! You could build your own too it's not that difficult except when it comes to non-standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll likely know the structure, it seems you could use XStream.

similar question: [How do I convert XML into a java value object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779755/how-do-i-convert-xml-into-a-java-value-object)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of libraries in Android you can use, plus a lot of external XML libraries. XML Pull Parser and SAX Parsers come with Android, at least from 1.6 as far as I know. XML Pull parser is more C-like, while SAX parser is more Java-like. There's also the DOM parser.

I ended up using the SAX parser for one project, and I used a Stack in order to keep track of where I am in the XML tree.