# Get text from XML between tags in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have xml entries like the following. I want to extract everything after the d:index tag closes to the end of entry.

```
<d:entry id="some_id" d:title="some_title">
        <d:index d:value="some_value"/>
        <h1>headlines</h1>

        <p>paragraphs</p>
        <div>
           <ul>
              <li>lists</li>

           </ul>
        </div>
        text like that
</d:entry>
```

I tried using

```
dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
eList = doc.getElementsByTagName("d:entry");
for (int i = 0; i < eList.getLength(); i++){
    Node nNode = eList.item(i);
    textList[i] = nNode.getTextContent();
}
```

But, .getTextContent() only gives me 'text like that' and not

```
<h1>headlines</h1>

<p>paragraphs</p>
   <div>
     <ul>
      <li>lists</li>

     </ul>
   </div>
text like that
```

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000) is a good resource.

Comment: *"extract everything"* In what form? "Everything" includes XML tags, so do you want DOM nodes (since you're using DOM), or do you want the result converted back to text? Would it be fair to say that you want the entire content of `<d:entry>` as text, excluding the `<d:index>` element, because if you look at it like that, it may be easier to handle.

Comment: thanks for your comments, edited my post

Comment: I found this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300839/get-a-nodes-inner-xml-as-string-in-java-dom
the innerXml helper function does what I was looking for, just need to remove the first line.

Comment: When I turn your code snippet in a full program, I get all the text nodes (i.e., "headlinesparagraphsliststext like that"). If that is what you meant, you must be doing something differently in your setup. Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you want the XML structure (as per your last update), you cannot use `getTextContent` because that only looks for text contents, not child elements. For those you need to call `getChildNodes` and recurse over them, printing (or otherwise using) the nodes as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you exactly want to do, you could do something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Arbeiter {

public void arbeiten(File datei)
{
    Document doc = getDoc(datei);
    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
    print(element);
}

private Document getDoc(File datei)
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(datei);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}

private void print(Node node)
{
    for (int i=0; i<node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++)
    {
        print(node.getFirstChild());
    }
    if(node.getTextContent()!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
    }
}

}
```

The output is:

```
headlines
    paragraphs     
          lists
    text like that
```