# java.lang.AbstractMethodError , Get a node's inner XML as String in Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948326/9454856

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl.createLSSerializer()Lorg/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer;

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of AbstractMethodError says:

*Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.*

So you've got some kind of configuration or version control problem in your code, probably you're picking up a different version of Apache Xerces at run time from the version used at compile time; though it also suggests you might be straying outside the stable API into calling methods that weren't really intended for public use.

As I can't see your code, there's a lot of guesswork here. The next stage in debugging would be to look at a stack trace.