# .NET XMLSerializer equivalence in Java/Android?

Tags: .net, android, xml, xml-serialization, equivalence

I've Googled the XMLSerializer in Android, but I found it's totally different from .NET. What I need is that, from a Serializable Class, I can write them to a XML file, and then read the XML file to return the class's properties values automically.

I need that because: I'm creating a game for Android, with a lot of settings and levels, so I design them by a editor made by .NET. Now I want that the XML file can be read by both the editor (by .NET) and the game (by Java/Android SDK). The class should be totally the same (all the properties, methods, names, ...).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java/35821#35821).  Sounds similar to the jackson parser bindings, which can serialize and unserialize Java objects and beans to/from JSON.

Comment: Thank you. Hope it is easy like on .NET.