# How can I send different data to rabbitmq?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

My work requires the queues get 3 different pieces of data to work. an int, a double and a int[] list.

From the tutorials I only see single Strings being sent.  Can I send multiple types of data in a queue without having to convert it to a string?

Edit: my work around I figured was to convert everything to a string and I can submit it one at a time but what about queues that have require multiple data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ messages are simply streams of bytes. You can send whatever you want in these messages, so if you're doing this from Java you should pick a serializer to convert your objects into byte streams of XML or JSON or whatever you prefer:

[XML serialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java)

http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/