# send object using HTTPservletResponse

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a client-server program that are using servlets to communicate with each other, each of them is sending an object (of a class that I defined) to the other.
Can I send it directly using the setContentType(myClass) in the servlet?
Or do I need to something completely different? I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize the object at server side, send it as an array of bytes, or encoded as a text (using base64 for example), and than deserialize it at the client side.

Comment: how can I serialize an image file? in my object U have a few strings and lists and an image

Comment: Yes, you can uses standard [java serialization API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). But this will only work if client and server has equal JRE version. In case you need support for different versions of JRE, you can [serialize to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative approach: use WebServices. You can get to know more about them at [Apache AXIS website](http://axis.apache.org/axis/).