# How do I store variables for later in Java?

Tags: java, variables, save, points

I want to make a point system for math game I'm making in Java. You start off with 0 points, and that increases at the end of the game, but when you restart the game, you get 0 points again. How can I get the value of the points from the last time I played the game? For example; I play the game, the value increases to 14, I close the game, turn it back on, and the value is still 14.

Comment: When you say _close the game_, do you mean you stop java?

Comment: You store them somewhere, such as a file or database. Search for how to do that, give it a go, and come back if you run into specific issues.

Comment: Yes the better way is to serialize the object and when you restart the program deserialize it to get that value

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist the variables in some way, so that when the program opens again, the variables are loaded with their original values.

The easiest way to accomplish this is probably to serialize a java object to XML, and then deserialize it when the program opens.  See [XML serialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java) for a starting point.