# Serialize one object into several different xml

Tags: java, xml, serialization, marshalling

i have one question. What is the best way to serialize in java 1 object to few xml with different schema? For example we have this java bean:

```
class User { 
   String name;
   String gender;
   String age;
}
```

And i want to serialize it to first

> ```
> <user>
>     <name>bobby</name>
>     <gender>male</gender>
>     <age>40</age>
> </user>
> ```

second

> ```
> <info>
>     <employer>
>         <data>
>             <name>bobby</name>
>         </data>
>         <meta>
>             <gender>male</gender>
>             <age>40</age>
>         </meta>
>     </employer>
> </info>
> ```

and maybe another one xml. What you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java). The JAXB lib generate the serialization xml file based on a .xsd file. And of course you can customize the .xsd file for your own purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

1. **Metadata Representation**

   Generally object-to-XML providers offer different ways of specifying metadata.  Annotations is one way of specifying metadata and in all instances of seen annotations correspond to only one representation.  So you need to look for a provider that offers an alternate approach such as an XML mapping document or programmatic metadata.
2. **Path Based Mapping**

   Generally object-to-XML providers offer mapping through a 1-to-1 relationship between objects/properties and levels of nesting.  To map to your second representation you need a provider that is able to do path based mapping.

MOXy offers both items that you are looking for.  Below is a link to an example where a single object model is mapped to both the Google and Yahoo weather APIs:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html