# Converting Java Object to Xml and vice versa

Tags: java, xml, serialization

Suppose I have an Employee Class which has a reference of another class say address which has its own attributes. So please let me know how to convert that into xml file and also the vice versa of it.

Thanks!!

Comment: The term is serialization and deserialization - look them up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML serialization in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

`JAXB` - It will help you to convert Object to XML and XML to Object. https://jaxb.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class that is part of the standard library.

**Java Object => XML**

```
JAXB.marshal(yourObject, new File("obj.xml"));
```

**XML => Java object**

```
YourClass yourObject = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("obj.xml"), YourClass.class);
```

You can customize the serialization/deserialization with annotation on the class and on its fields.