# Using a C++ Struct in Android app (Java and XML)?

Tags: java, android, c++, xml, structure

I'm a decent C++ programmer, good enough to do what I want.  But I'm working on my first Android App (obviously not C++ related), and I'm having an issue where I'd like to translate what I know from C++ over to the XML/Java used in Android Studio.

Basically I have (in C++) an array of structures.  And maybe I didn't do the perfect search, but I sure as heck tried to look around for the answer, but I didn't come up with anything.

How would I go about placing an array of structures inside the XML file and utilizing it in Java?

As a bit of a buffer, let me say that I'm not really looking for code, just verification that this is possible, and a method on how to go about it.  I don't mind researching to learn what I want, but I haven't come up with anything.  Like I said, I probably haven't googled it properly because I'm unsure of exactly how to ask it.

EDIT:  So it appears that XML doesn't have a structure (or anything similar? not sure).  But I can utilize a Java class with public variables.  Now my question is more or less: What would be the best way to go about inserting all the information into the array/class/variables?

In C++ terms, I could neatly place all the info into a text file and then read from it, using a FOR loop to place all the info in the structures.  Or, if I don't want to use an outside source/file, I could hardcode the information into each variable.  Tedious, but it'd work.  I'm not sure, in Android terms, if I could use the same method and pack in a text file with the app, and read from the file using a FOR loop to insert the information into the array/class/variables

```
class answerStruct
{
    public String a;

    public boolean status;

};



class questionStruct
{
    public String q;

    answerStruct[] answer = new answerStruct[4];

};
```

I'm not placing this here to brag at my super high tech program, but to give a visual, and frankly that's less I have to write out.  This is the method I plan on going with.  But, being Java, I'm open to possibly better options.  My question still stands as far as inputting information into the variables.  Hard code? or does Android/Java allow me to place a text file with my app, and read from it into the variables?

Comment: Java has no concept of structs. Everything (except for the 6 primitive types) is a class in Java. So the equivalent of an array of structs in C++ is an array (or `ArrayList`) of objects. XML representation is completely up to you. There is no good or wrong. If you can't make up your mind, I'd suggest `<listOfMyStruct><myStruct><property name="x" value="y1"/></myStruct><myStruct><property name="x" value="y2"/></myStruct></listOfMyStruct>`

Comment: @taoufik, Thanks for the prompt reply, I appreciate it and it verified what I recently found (of course, after I actually posted here go figure).  If you would, check out the edit to my post.  With my recent findings, my question has transformed a bit.  Again, thanks.  By the way, I'm going to look into your suggestion, so it wasn't for nothing :-)

Answer (score 0):

XML is just a markup language for tree-structured data, and imposes no restrictions on how you name or structure your tree nodes.

What I think that you're looking for is an `XML Object Serialiser`: a way to serialise your in-memory structure into XML for a more permanent storage, and then at a later run, deserialise it back into memory. There are many [XML Serialisers for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785/xml-serialization-in-java), each with an own proprietary XML format.

I've used [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php) in the past, and found it easy and flexible.